# I created a constructor and getting error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method how can i fix?

Tags: c#, android

My project is in c# using xamarin android.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace App5
{
    [Activity(Label = "App5", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;



        public MainActivity()
        {

            var langAvailable = new List<string> { "Default" };
            var localesAvailable = Java.Util.Locale.GetAvailableLocales().ToList();
            foreach (var locale in localesAvailable)
            {
                LanguageAvailableResult res = TextToSpeech.IsLanguageAvailable(locale);
                switch (res)
                {
                    case LanguageAvailableResult.Available:
                        langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                        break;
                    case LanguageAvailableResult.CountryAvailable:
                        langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                        break;
                    case LanguageAvailableResult.CountryVarAvailable:
                        langAvailable.Add(locale.DisplayLanguage);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

On this line:

```
TextToSpeech.IsLanguageAvailable(locale)
```

I'm getting the error:

**Error 1** : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property **Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.IsLanguageAvailable(Java.Util.Locale)**

tried to change the constructor to be static or the variable `LanguageAvailableResult` to be static but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tts=new TextToSpeech();
LanguageAvailableResult res=tts.IsLanguageAvailable(locale);
```

Comment: TextToSpeech instance need to get arguments. At least two. Context and texttospeech.ionlistener.

Comment: Then you need to supply them.

Comment: And I tried I created global TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener listen; but I don't understand what should I assign it to. Then in the TextToSpeech instance I did: new TextToSpeech(ApplicationContext,listen); so now i'm not getting errors but listen is not assigned so it's null.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Xamarin, so I can't help you there.